# Rendering,blender,curvpath

Tags: rendering

Why are my nurbspath lines showing while rendering?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: It looks like you are in *Edit Mode* (otherwise we could not see a curve handle ?). But it is hard to be sure with just a truncated screen view... By *rendering*, do you mean using *Render/Render Image* menu, or in the 3D Viewport ?

Comment: The lines are showing because you are not rendering - to render you hit `F12` or choose _Render_ > _Render Image_ from the top menu.. What you see is a render **preview**, but it has the viewport overlays showing if you do not disable them. And especially when you are in _Edit Mode_ as it seems, you see the inherent structures more than in _Object Mode_.